# Definir um valor para o select do Material Design Lite

Tags: material-design

Eu estou tentando inserir alguns dados no select do meu formulario, estou usando [mdl-select](http://creativeit.github.io/getmdl-select/)

O problema é que estou tentando inserir um valor mas simplesmente não funciona.

Gostaria que o valor buscado no banco de dados fosse inserido no select. o que esta errado?

```html
<!-- Simple Select -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">

<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://creativeit.github.io/getmdl-select/getmdl-select.min.css">

<script defer src="http://creativeit.github.io/getmdl-select/getmdl-select.min.js"></script>


    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield getmdl-select">
        <input type="text" value="" class="mdl-textfield__input" id="sample1" readonly>
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="sample1">
        <label for="sample1" class="mdl-textfield__label">Country</label>
        <ul for="sample1" class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu">
            <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="DEU">Germany</li>
            <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="BLR">Belarus</li>
            <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="RUS">Russia</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
                                            
<script>
//Set value
$('#sample1').val('RUS')
</script>
```

Comment: Note que o valor RUS some ao clicar em outra parte da tela.

Comment: Não deu para entender, está funcionando normal.

Comment: O valor esperado para RUS é  Russia, alem disso o valor some da tela. Analisando no Dev Tools do Chrome é possivel ver que a tag value fica vazia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pré selecionar uma opção é necessário usar o atributo `data-selected`, você pode adiciona-lo diretamente ao HTML:

```
<li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="RUS" data-selected="true">Russia</li>
```

Ou pelo jQuery:

```
$('[data-val="RUS"]').attr('data-selected', true)
```

Exemplo funcionando:

```html
<!-- Simple Select -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">

<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://creativeit.github.io/getmdl-select/getmdl-select.min.css">

<script defer src="http://creativeit.github.io/getmdl-select/getmdl-select.min.js"></script>


<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield getmdl-select">
    <input type="text" value="" class="mdl-textfield__input" id="sample1" readonly>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="sample1">
    <label for="sample1" class="mdl-textfield__label">Country</label>
    <ul for="sample1" class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu">
        <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="DEU">Germany</li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="BLR">Belarus</li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="RUS">Russia</li>
    </ul>
</div>
                                            
<script>
  //Set value
  $('#sample1').val('RUS')
  $('[data-val="RUS"]').attr('data-selected', true)
</script>
```

Ainda é necessário manter a linha que seta o valor:

```
$('#sample1').val('RUS')
```

Se não, apesar de visualmente selecionado, o valor do input será uma string vazia